# Tests run slower with Maven than with IDE

Tags: maven, testing, time, execution

I'm facing some test time execution issue related to local test execution with Maven. I have around 250 tests which run about 15 min on the IDE test runner and about an hour (55min to be exact) when executing them with maven locally. I tried a lot of configurations to make test execution in parallel but neither of them work for me, the time is still the same...probably I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone help on this? The last maven surefire plugin configuration that I tried is the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <parallel>methods</parallel>
      <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And for test execution command I've used:

- mvn test
- mvn surefire:test

Comment: First why are you using such an old version of surefire? Which JDK ? Which Maven version do you use? Really 250 unit tests taking 15 minutes ? That sounds like integration tests and *not* unit tests...which IDE/JDK you you are using? Memory configuration? IDE vs. Command line?

Comment: JDK version 13, Maven: v3.6.2. Yes, these are integration tests, I didn't say that they are unit tests. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. What do you mean by memory configuration? I'm using such old version of surefire because the newer ones cause some other errors for some reason and the result is always "Build failure" and no tests are run

Comment: My assumption was based on using surefire for tests which is usually used for unit tests whereas failsafe is used for integration tests. If you have build failures my assumption is you are using old plugins which do not work with JDK13 ...then we might need to figure out the issue for the build failure first and afterwards the problems with the tests....

Comment: I've tried with a lot versions of the surefire plugin, starting from 2.19 to the last one which currently is 3.0.0-M4, but the result was the same. What version should I use with JDK 13? And if I replace surefire with failsafe, then what configuration do you recommend me?

Comment: The first thing is to identify the cause of the failure...so log output would help what has failed cause you mentioned "build failures" ...

Comment: Ok. Minutes ago I've tried to run tests with failsafe plugin and used the following config: <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/testng_suites/${suite}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <parallel>methods</parallel>
          <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project AirGlance: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Repos/airglance-lht/airglance-integration-tests/src/main/java/com/upnetix/api/services/IGetProjectSpecifics.java:[9,18] package org.testng does not exist
....
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project AirGlance: Compilation failure

Comment: You are missing TESTNG dependency...

Comment: No, I'm not. I have it in the dependancies tag: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: But based on the above error message there is something wrong...could you post the whole pom file ...or even a more less equivalent? Have you defined it in dependencyManagement only? Do you have a project on GitHub ?

Comment: Here is the whole pom.xml file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SQJ6rCuj7_U7ge5-5zyvJCPDy_5DTcV7

Comment: Some comments: Never use `RELEASE` as version better use fixed versions like 6.3.1 instead for all of your dependencies. Do not mix versions for surefire/failsafe always use the same versions for both of them..can you make a github project of those pom file with a simple test to see what the real issue is? How have you names your test cases?

Comment: I isolated a project with some sample tests and I've used the same pom as in the real project, but the issue didn't reproduce. When I added one of the test classes from the real project to the isolated project, then the build started to fail and the error said that there are test failures, but there wasn't any output in the console with these test failures. I cannot upload it on Github, because it requires a VPN with a token in order for the tests to be run. But thank you for your help...::)